# Flot Bar Chart Data Conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am trying to make a simple bar chart but my data is not appearing

var data = [["item1",277],["item2",635],["item3",133]]

Can you please show me how to convert the string above to the correct format for Flot?

Please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q7R68/

```
var data = [["item1",277],["item2",635],["item3",133]] 

var options = {
                    series: {
                        stack: 0,
                        lines: { show: false, steps: false },
                        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.9, align: 'center', },
                    }
                };

alert(data);
$.plot($("#statsChart2"), data, options);
```

Thanks

EDIT: I should have been more clear in my question that I would like to convert the data from its string representation to what is needed by Flot through code. It represents a JSON array that has been converted to string format to be graphed

Comment: @captain Hi, I tried in fiddle but still no graph

Comment: Please check my ans [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7R68/3/) Please update if needed any help.Mark has also provide fiddle depicting ticks may be the one you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is all confused.  The `bars` and `lines` config belongs in the data while your axis labels ("item1", etc...) belong in your options.

Finally, I don't see a `stack` option in the API

```
var data = [[0,277],[1,635],[2,133]];

var aSeries = {
    data: data,
    bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.9, align: 'center' }
};

var someOptions = {
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0,"item1"],[1,"item2"],[2,"item3"]]   
     }       
};

$.plot($("#statsChart2"), [aSeries], someOptions);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q7R68/2/).

**EDITS**

I guess I'm feeling generous today here's a quick snippet of code to do the conversion:

```
var data = [["item1",277],["item2",635],["item3",133]];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ticks.push([i,data[i][0]]);
    data[i][0] = i;   
}
```

Updated, updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7R68/5/).

Comment: Hello, I should have been more clear in my question that I would like to convert the data from its string representation to what is needed by Flot through code. It represents a JSON array that has been converted to string format to be graphed

Comment: OK, I've showed you the correct way to call flot, now what have **you** tried to do the conversion?  Oh nevermind, I'll just do it for you.  See edits above.

Comment: Its one and the same thing you doing .I guess the correct way is to specify the tick array array done in first example.

Comment: @Mark Thanks guys this is great and I have learned much about using Flot